# Avoiding duplicate object properties

Tags: java

using a jframe i am trying to create a list of students, save them onto a file, re-read all those students and create new ones if, and only if, their id numbers are not the same. If the ID numbers are the same i am supposed to get an error message saying that that ID is already in use and thus not be able to register the new student. The only problem here is that even if the ID has already been used, it registers the students. What am i doing wrong?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class NewEstudiantesJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public static List <Estudiantes> EstReg = new ArrayList<>(); 
public static Long ci, ciprueba;

public NewEstudiantesJFrame() {

    initComponents();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

private void AceptarButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

    Estudiantes estu = new Estudiantes(); 

 try {
       FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("t.txt");
       ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
       EstReg = (List<Estudiantes>) ois.readObject();
       ois.close();// es necesario cerrar el input stream

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {

    }     

    String NumId = new String();

    String tipoId = (String) TipoIdBox.getSelectedItem();
    estu.TipoId = tipoId;

    NumId = NumIdField.getText();
     if ((NumId.length()>9)||(NumId.length()<8)){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Type in the 8 or 9 ID digits");
         a++;
         NumIdField.setText(null);
         //NumIdField.requestFocusInWindow();
     }
     else
        { ci = Long.parseLong(NumId);
     }


    try{
          **for (Estudiantes e : EstReg){
            if (e.NumId == Long.parseLong(NumId)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ID already in use, please check your data");
                NumIdField.setText(null);
                NumIdField.requestFocusInWindow();
        }

        else {
            estu.NumId = ci;
    }**
    }
    }

    catch (NumberFormatException  ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inpult only ID numbers");
        a++;
    }
```

Here's my Estudiantes class

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Estudiantes implements Serializable{

String Nombre;
String Apellido;
String Direccion;
String Email;
String CursoActual;
String TipoId;
Long NumId;
String IdTotal;
String CodTel;
Long NumTel;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Serialization doesn't have anything apparent to do witn this question.

Comment: Or Swing, or ArrayList either.

Comment: Override equals method and use EstReg.contains(e). Don't see the write to file here. Is it implemented? If so, try printing the list after read. Initially the list would go null. Do a null check after read and initialize the list.

Comment: @user3330990 You didn't show the implementation of how you instantiate an Estudiantes object. The problem lies in there. You also have to show how the file is read. There are a number of problems in your codes which I will only be able to give an answer after you posted everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will work but try using .compareTo() when comparing both of the longs instead of ==. Then check to see if the resulting value is equal zero. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compareTo-java.lang.Long-

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my bad, i just realized i hadn't shown the rest of the code... Really sorry about that. I had to take a previous version of the same file and go with the .compareTo option. Thanks for the link Bryan Herrera.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class NewEstudiantesJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

   public static List <Estudiantes> EstReg = new ArrayList<>(); 

public NewEstudiantesJFrame() {

    initComponents();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

private void AceptarButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

    Estudiantes estu = new Estudiantes(); 

 try {
       FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\t.txt");
       ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
       EstReg = (List<Estudiantes>) ois.readObject();
       ois.close();

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {

    }     

    String NumId = new String();
    String nombre = new String();
    String numTel = new String();
    nombre = NombreField.getText();
    String apellido = ApellidoField.getText();
    String direccion = DireccionArea.getText();
    String codtel;
    boolean curso;
    curso = false;
    int a = 0;

    String tipoId = (String) TipoIdBox.getSelectedItem();
    estu.TipoId = tipoId;

    if ((nombre.length()== 0)|| apellido.isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please type in students full name");
        a++;
    }
    else{
    estu.Nombre = NombreField.getText();
    estu.Apellido = ApellidoField.getText();

    if (direccion.length()== 0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please input Student's address");
        a++;
    }
    else{
        estu.Direccion = DireccionArea.getText();}

    }

     try {
        NumId = NumIdField.getText();
     if ((NumId.length()!=8)){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please type in the 8 digits if your ID");
         a++;
         NumIdField.setText(null);

     else{
        estu.NumId = Long.parseLong(NumId);
}
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inpult only ID numbers");
        a++;
    }
    for (Estudiantes es: EstReg){
        if (es.NumId.compareTo(estu.NumId)==0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ID already in use, please check your data");
            NumIdField.setText(null);
            a++;
        }
    }

     try  {
        numTel = NumTelField.getText();
        if (numTel.length()!=7){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please type in the 7 telephone number digits");
            a++;
        }
        else
        estu.NumTel = Long.parseLong(numTel);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException ex){ 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error. Only accepts numbers");
        NumTelField.setText(null);
        a++;
    }

    if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()){
        estu.CursoActual= "Maths 1";
        curso = true;
    }
    if (jRadioButton2.isSelected()){
        estu.CursoActual ="Maths 2";
        curso = true;
    }
    if (jRadioButton3.isSelected()){
        estu.CursoActual ="Maths 3";
        curso = true;
    }
    if ((curso == false) || (a > 0)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please finish filling the form out");     
    }
    else{
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        try {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student succesfully registered. Thank you!");

            estu.IdTotal = tipoId + NumId;
            EstReg.add(estu);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\t.txt");
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(EstReg);
            oos.close();
            this.dispose();
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }
}
```